# How do get class variable within an event handler with "this"

Tags: javascript

Here is some code:

```
var class = function(elem,div){

    this.elem= elem;
    this.div = div;

    this.init = function(){
        this.div.bind('keyup',this.handler);
    }

    this.handler= function(event){
        //HOW DO I GET "this.elem" ???
        //here, this = div
    }

    this.init();
}
```

I want to get the variable "elem" from within my "handler" function, but everytime i call this.elem, the "this" is referring to the elem that was bound to the event handler!!.

Comment: You've found the biggest problem in JavaScript. (I'm still trying to deeply understand "this" myself. It has something to do with binding the closure context. Or something.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could just reference `elem`.

Or you could declare `var that = this;` outside of the the handler and then reference `that.elem`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are registering `this.handler` as the event handler itself.  In this case, the method is not being executed in the context of the object; it's being executed like any other event handler.

Try writing a simple handler that invokes your `handler` method on an instance of class.

```
var instance = new class(...); // populate args that make sense 
document.yourElement.onclick = function(){
   instance.handler();
}
```

Also, you really should use prototype to define instance methods.  Doing it the way you are doing it is very inefficient.

```
var class = function(elem,div){

    this.elem= elem;
    this.div = div;

    this.init();
}


class.prototype.init = function(){
        this.div.bind('keyup',this.handler);
    }

class.prototype.handler= function(event){
        //HOW DO I GET "this.elem" ???
        //here, this = div
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're cool in using `ES5`, you might want to invoke the `Function.prototype.bind` method. Like

```
this.handler= function(event){
    //HOW DO I GET "this.elem" ???
    //here, this = div
}.bind(this)
```

There are also lots of shims for that method available to gracefully support old'ish browsers. The above code would cause that the function which is stored in `this.handler` gets bound to the value of `this` when the method is called like `new class();` forever.

Comment: The OP wants to get a reference to the identifier *elem*, not the instance. It's held in a closure to it can be accessed as simply  `elem`.

Answer (score 0):

`elem` is captured in a closure, simply reference it as `elem`:

```
this.handler= function (event) {
     //HOW DO I GET "this.elem" ???
     //here,

     elem; // elem from the constructor.

     this = div
}
```

Also

1. there are no classes in javascript.
2. *class* is a reserved word and you should not use it for an identifier name.
3. I guess from your names and the way you used them that *elem* is a DOM element and *div* is a DIV element. If so, they don't have a *bind* method. If you want to assign a listener, then:

   ```
   this.onkeyup = this.handler;
   ```

but that must be placed after you define `this.handler`.